# PC only fast-charges phone if plugged in while asleep or turned off

Tags: windows-11, charging, phone

I bought my Lenovo PC a couple of years ago. It used to fast charge my Galaxy S10 whenever I plugged it in via USB3.1 och USB C. Now it only does that if i plug my phone in while the PC is in sleep mode or turned off. Also, if I do that and start the computer afterwards, it continues to fast charge, until I plug my phone out.

If the computer is on and I plug it in, my phone will first say that it's fast charging and give me an estimate of like 2hrs for a full charge, but after a few seconds it will go up to 5 hrs. I can't figure out what's going on.

Just a note, my phone is a few years old, so "fast charging" isn't all that fast.

Comment: I have 2 Lenovo laptops like this and the blue USB always ON port works fine.  Try updating BIOS on the machine and also power drivers

Comment: If the Lenovo is a laptop, it could be the Lenovo battery is getting weak, and the extra drain of charging the phone now overloads the charger. Check battery stats. Also, if *not* laptop, have you made changes such as adding a SSD or HDD, or changed graphics card, drawing more current?

Comment: No it's a desktop. Hmm, yes I did add a HDD...but that doesnt explain the sleep behaviour though